Loading windows sequentially
I'm trying to load two windows sequentially, but first does not load properly. What can be the reason? Am i blocking some UI render thread with second window data?
private void loadFormWithLoadingScreen<Type>() 
    where Type : Window, new()
{
    //first step:
    LoadingScreen loadingScreen = new LoadingScreen
    {
        Owner = this,
        Topmost = true
    };

    this.Hide();
    loadingScreen.Activate();
    loadingScreen.Show();
    loadingScreen.toCenter(this);

    //second step:
    Type win = new Type
    {
        Owner = this,
        Topmost = true
    };
    win.Unloaded += (_s, _e) =>
    {
        this.Show();
        this.Activate();
    };
    win.Loaded += (_s, _e) =>
    {
        loadingScreen.Close();
    };

    win.toCenter(this);
    win.Show();
}


I assume this is like a splash screen. Loading needs to open do it's thing then as it closes the other opens up but neither of them at the same time?

Your tag says it's in WPF you can do all this inside your OnStartup method. This is how I have always made loading screens and splash screens in WPF.
Don't forget to the change your StartupUri in the App.xaml.
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    var splashScreen = new CoolScreen();
    //any other application work here. CoolScreen class can handle the rest.
    splashScreen.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
    splashScreen.Show();

    var yourMainWindow = new MainWindow();
    yourMainWindow.ContentRendered += (sender, args) =>
    {
        //This doesn't have to be in the ContentRendered method
        // but it is necesary because you'll be closing out a window before another is open.
        Application.Current.MainWindow = yourMainWindow;
        Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose;
        //Accessing the dispatcher of the thread for splashScreen from another
        // thread could be dangerous but, you do need to have the other thread close the splashScreen window out.
        splashScreen.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => splashScreen.Close());
    };
    yourMainWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
    yourMainWindow.Show();
}

I can make edits to it as needed. I made a lot of assumptions.

Maybe i am missing something, but is there OnStartup method for Window class in WPF? Or how do i have to implement it?

In the App.xaml.cs or whereever your main entry method is that inherits the Application class. It's an event of the Application class. I also forgot to include the base.OnStartup(e) call.

As i understood, this method rather for creation of loading screen before first window showed, but i need this transition in between the nested(children) windows.

Just so I understand. It would go: window A opens window B and B closes A. Then B does something and opens window C. Is this the pattern? If that's the case then you can subscribe to the ContentRendered event for window C and have it close out your window B so window B would call a method that looks like the one in the answer. C being yourMainWindow and window B being the splashScreen.
